# Android: getSupportActionBar().setTitle("...") требует runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Доброго времени суток всем. Есть необходимость, чтобы каждую минуту заголовок моего `ActionBar` в `Activity` изменялся. Там должно отображаться время формата `mm:ss`. Естественно, я не буду заниматься таким процессом в главном потоке, и я создал отдельный. Но вот эта команда

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").format(new Date(this.time)));
```

требует, чтобы я запустил её в главном потоке, и не в каком ином, так как вылетает `Exception`. Покопался в интернете, где мне сказали, что можно сделать таким образом

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").format(new Date(this.time)));
    }

});
```

Но, к сожалению, этот вариант не очень то хорош. К сороковой минуте моё приложение вылетело по неизвестной причине. Разобрался в логах, и выяснил, что слишком много миллисекунд занимает запуск команды `runOnUiThread`, в последствии чего эта команда одновременно была запущена дважды. Я заметил, что заголовок мой изменяется неравномерно. Должен ведь обновляться через 1000 мс, что значит секунда, а обновляется то 900 мс, то 1200 мс и так далее. С чем это связано я не знаю. Как решить проблему, чтобы заголовок менялся **ровно** каждые 1000 мс?

Я попрошу вас не предлагать мне просто не использовать заголовок, а создать какой-нибудь свой, к примеру, `TextView` в `Activity`. Также, плохой вариант `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(...)`, как описано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883732/how-to-display-custom-view-in-actionbar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогла [эта статья](http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/02/14/android-oshibka-only-the-original-thread-that-created-a-view-hierarchy-can-touch-its-views.html) и пользователь @Kota1921, благодаря которому понял, где нужно копать.

Нужно создать глобальную переменную:

```
private Handler i6;
```

В методе `onCreate(...)` объявить эту переменную:

```
this.i6 = new Handler() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message i1) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<i>" + Game.this.i2[0].getProperty("style_textColor") + "\">" + i1.obj + "</i>"));
    }

};
```

И вот отсюда:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    private Long i1 = 0L;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            ...
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
            this.i1 += 1000L;
            Message i2 = new Message();
            i2.obj = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").format(new Date(this.i1));
            MyActivity.this.i6.sendMessage(i2);
        }
    }

}).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

А как насчет Handler, который позволяет выполнять отложенный код? Вот пример:

```
private final int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable timeUpdaterRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //тут что нибудь делается
};
```

А вот запуск отложенной задачи:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(this, ONE_SECOND);
```

Comment: Где у Вас комментарий `//тут что-нибудь делается` можно вставить `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...)`?

Comment: Да, можно вставить. Вроде даже не надо указывать runOnUiThread, но это не точно.

Comment: Нет, `Handler` не подходит: `Exception: only the original thread that... can touch it views`

Comment: Ну так сделай runOnUiThread, в чем проблема?

Comment: В этом и проблема

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в главном потоке запустить подобный код:

```
Thread thread = new Thread("Run update") {
        public void run(){


            try {
                initServer();

            } catch (Exception e1) {

                System.out.println("Cant create.. "+e1);
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

где initServer:

```
     private initServer(){
isServerWorking=true;

    Вместо isServerWorking вставляем любую проверку остановки нашего 
    обновления(приложение закрыто системой, пользователь закрыл программу и т.д.)

                    while (isServerWorking){

    В методе update() прописываем всю нужную нам логику
                        update();

                        try {

    Задержка небольшая, чтобы бесконечно не обновлялось, иначе процесс будет уж очень много кушать
                            Thread.sleep(MILLSECUPDATE);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }}
```

Надеюсь, идея понятна.